# iPhone: UITableView performance issue with imageWithContentsOfFile

Tags: iphone, performance, image, uitableview

I have performance issue in UITableView scrolling when I use imageWithContentsOfFile instead of imageNamed. Following is my code:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UniversalAppAppDelegate *delegate = (UniversalAppAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSDictionary *res = [[delegate comments] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

if (cell == nil) 
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

 ......

// This line has a problem...when I use imageNamed here instead of imageWithContentsOfFile, it works absolutely fine
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagepath]];
[imageView setFrame: CGRectMake(30, 10, 55, 55)];
[sectionHeaderView addSubview:imageView];

......

cell.backgroundView = sectionHeaderView;
return cell;
```

I have also tried [caching](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/) image but still same issue. Only imageNamed works perfectly fine but I can't use it as I need to specify path for image stored in documents folder and changes dynamically. Could anyone please tell me how could I resolve this issue?

Caching code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *thumbnailCache = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

- (UIImage*)thumbnailImage:(NSString*)fileName
{
UIImage *thumbnail = [thumbnailCache objectForKey:fileName];

if (nil == thumbnail)
{
    NSString *thumbnailFile = [self filePath:fileName];
    thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:thumbnailFile];
    [thumbnailCache setObject:thumbnail forKey:fileName];
}
return thumbnail;
}
```

Usage:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[delegate thumbnailImage:[res objectForKey:@"ImageName"]]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try building an array of UIImages in the `viewDidLoad` method of the controller, and use the images in that array in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

This will get rid of the need to call `imageWithContentsOfFile`  for each image when drawing the tableview.

You could for example build the array in a seperate thread, and show a loading indicator while this happens. It would mean a small loading time at first, but a smooth scrolling tableview.

Comment: That's what I meant by caching. I already doing it but that didn't help either. Added my caching code.

Comment: Ok thanks and what changes did you make inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`when you use the caching ?

Comment: My bad! I forgot to initialize this dictionary. Initialized and then it worked fine!